# Installing ROS on a remote PC to control Nao

Tags: ros, catkin, nao, nao-robot, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am trying to install the latest NAO stack as instructed in the ros-nao Wiki.

Unfortunately, I am using ROS Fuerte, which does not have catkin installed and I cannot operate under catkin workspace.

As far as I understood, the result is to be unable to properly install the NAO stack 0.2 under rosbuild. Furthermore, when I try the instructions for the 0.1 version, I noticed that it downloads again the 0.2 version.

Could you please help me finding the 0.1 version?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Bast,

Akis

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/103291/installing-ros-on-a-remote-pc-to-control-nao/) by [Akis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4464/akis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-11-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yao](https://answers.ros.org/users/37573/yao/) on 2018-09-18**:
Hello, I want to do the same things with you, I try to use nao_dcm_bringup package, but I got some matters. If i want to control a specific joint of nao, What packages should I install and what topic I need to pub to control the joints?  Could you please give me some suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The instructions at http://wiki.ros.org/nao/Installation/remote were missing version entries for the older releases, thus the rosinstall checkout always tried the latest versions on the master branch.

I added the versions to the "v0.1 (rosbuild)" rosinstall. Could you try if it works with the updated instructions?

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4464/akis/) on 2013-11-26**:
Hello,

Yes it works fine now. Thank you for your help.

Akis

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-11-26**:
If this answer is correct, please check the box above.